# lovemap concept

Tags: love

I got to know about a theory called as "lovemap" concept. It was propounded by John Money to explain the underlying concepts of amorous bonding (Although , broadly it covers the origin of sexual behavior of humans ). However, I couldn't conclude how accurate this theory is and is it scientifically acclaimed. I would like to have views about this from experts here.

Comment: As a starting point, have you gone to Google Scholar, checked the book where the idea is first expressed and then looked at [the articles that cite the book](https://scholar.google.ca/scholar?cites=13416431336278596919&as_sdt=2005&sciodt=1,5&hl=en)?

Comment: @Seanny123 : No...I thought views of experts here might help in a systematic way .

Comment: It's a pretty wide topic, so covering what you know would be really helpful.